# Prism MVVM ViewModel property backing field as model's property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, viewmodel

I am new to Prism MVVM and trying to create ViewModel properties which have backing field to Model's properties.

```
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
    {
        private Person model;
        public Person Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { SetProperty(ref model, value); }
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return Model.DisplayName; }
            set { SetProperty(ref Model.DisplayName, value); }
        }
```

But it generates compiler error at line:

```
set { SetProperty(ref Model.DisplayName, value); }
```

"A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter".

So how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to raise OnPropertyChanged manually and set it without the helper.

```
  public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return Model.DisplayName; }
        set 
        {
            Model.DisplayName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then I should also manually check if the value is different? public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return Model.DisplayName; }
            set
            {
                if (Model.DisplayName != value)
                {
                    Model.DisplayName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }                
            }
        }

Comment: In general, it is expected, that propertychanged event is fired only when the value really changes, so yes, you should check. But when it comes to databinding, there's no difference

Comment: Just a note for anyone running into this issue post Jan2019 - 

OnPropertyChanged is deprecated.  Use RaisePropertyChanged instead.  Other than that, this is wholly accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reflection` and create something like `BindableBaseExtended` which inherits from `Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase`.

```
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBaseExtended
{
    private Person model;
    public Person Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { SetProperty(ref model, value); }
    }
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return Model.DisplayName; }
        set { SetProperty(Model, m => m.DisplayName, value); }
    }
}

public class BindableBaseExtended : BindableBase
{
    protected virtual bool SetProperty<TClass, TMember>(TClass target, Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expression, TMember value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var expr = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
        var propValue = prop.GetValue(target, null);
        if (object.Equals(propValue, value)) return false;

        prop.SetValue(target, value, null);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected virtual bool SetProperty<TClass, TMember>(TClass target, Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expression, TMember value, Action onChanged, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var expr = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
        var propValue = prop.GetValue(target, null);
        if (object.Equals(propValue, value)) return false;

        prop.SetValue(target, value, null);
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure I can extend BindableBase and create my own BindableBase class, but is there any way without using reflection ?

Comment: If you don't want to use Reflection then you need to implement the logic of BindableBase.SetProperty on each of your ViewModel property to be able to wrap your Model's property. But if you prefer readability then this is one way to go.